# Rendering array of Strings in React with useState Hook

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to access links of the URL stored in a array named screenshots, when i try to fetch the result from back-end it's working fine while when i set my json to the state variable details it is concating it as a string. How do i render the URLs separately. I am new with react and tried so many things could not figure it out how to resolve this.

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

    const AppDetails = () => {
      const [Details, setDetails] = useState([]);
      let { appId } = useParams();
      const getDetails = async appId => {
        try {
          if (appId) {
            const response = await fetch(
              "http://localhost:5000/appdetails/" + appId
            );
            const jsonDetails = await response.json();
            console.log(jsonDetails.screenshots[0]);     //working fine
            setDetails(jsonDetails);
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      };

      useEffect(() => {
        getDetails(appId);
      }, []);
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <h1 className="text-center mt-5">App Details </h1>
          <h2 className="text-center mt-5">Title: {Details.title}</h2>
          <h2 className="text-center mt-5">Summary: {Details.summary}</h2>
          <h6 className="text-center mt-5">Description: {Details.description}</h6>
          <h3 className="text-center mt-5">Developed By: {Details.developer}</h3>
          <h3 className="text-center mt-5">Rating: {Details.scoreText}</h3>
          <div
            key={Details.appId}
            className="col-md-12 mt-5 panel panel-default"
            width="500px"
            height="500px"
          >
            <img
              src={Details.screenshots[0]}
              alt={Details.appId}
              width="200px"
              height="200px"
            />
            <img
              src={Details.screenshots[1]}
              alt={Details.appId}
              width="200px"
              height="200px"
            />
            <img
              src={Details.screenshots[2]}
              alt={Details.appId}
              width="200px"
              height="200px"
            />
            <img
              src={Details.icon}
              alt={Details.appId}
              width="200px"
              height="200px"
            />
            <img
              src={Details.screenshots[3]}
              alt={Details.appId}
              width="200px"
              height="200px"
            />
            <img
              src={Details.screenshots[4]}
              alt={Details.appId}
              width="200px"
              height="200px"
            />
          </div>
        </Fragment>
      );
    };

    export default AppDetails;
```

Comment: Try having object with default value props in  const [Details, setDetails] = useState({appId : null ,screenshots:[] });

Comment: the issue persists

Comment: setDetails({...Details,...jsonDetails})

Comment: not helpful instead it's showing type-error i.e. jsonDetails is not iterable
    at getDetails